# PHP errors not logged in separated log file

Tags: php, logging, apache2, virtualhost

I want to log apache2 and php errors in separated files:

I create a directory in: `/var/log/apache2/mydomain.com`. this is the location where the log files are stored.

I edited my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerAlias mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public

php_flag display_errors Off
php_flag log_errors On
php_value log_errors_max_len 0
php_value error_reporting 6135


ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mydomain.com/mydomain.com.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mydomain.com/mydomain.com.access.log common
php_value error_log /var/log/apache2/mydomain.com/mydomain.com.php.error.log

<Directory "/var/www/mydomain.com/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Important settings:

- php_flag display_errors Off
- php_flag log_errors On
- php_value log_errors_max_len 0
- php_value error_reporting 6135
- php_value error_log /var/log/apache2/mydomain.com/mydomain.com.php.error.log

But the file: `mydomain.com.php.error.log` is not created, instead all the PHP errors are added to the mydomain.com.error.log file.

apache2 is able to write in the directory: `/var/log/mydomain.com` (tested, if i remove the file: `mydomain.com.error.log`. it will be recreated)

there are no log related settings in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

when i edit the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.conf` file, i run: `sudo service apache2 restart` afterwards.

Do you see anything that is wrong or is there a reason why it might not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
php_value error_log /var/log/apache2/mydomain.com/mydomain.com.php.error.log
```

`php_value` only works if php is enabled under apache i.e `mod_php`. Also following suggestion might help.

1. You don't have correct file permission
2. Create the log file yourself and check again.